# Println cannot find symbol

Tags: java, println

Im just started to learn Java and have a problem, hope you can help me.

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Main {

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public void main(String[] args) {
// TODO code application logic here

}
Date date = new Date();
long millis = date.getTime();
System.out.println(date);      <-- here i have a problem!
}
```

Print out dont working, i dont know why. Please help!

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Now i see, my fail. Thanks guiys!

Comment: your code is outside the method body

Comment: When do you think that code should be executed? Why do you think so? (hint: why is your `main` method empty?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in main method or create a new method with all the statement that was want to execute:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   //date...
   //print
}
```

Or

```
private static void printDate() {
   //date stuff goes here.....
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
   printDate();
}
```

Main is the entry point from where the execution will begin. You would need to accumulate all the statements under a method or into main method to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `System.out.println()` within a method. Try entering it inside a method.